# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in a LazyVGrid

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios14

I've implemented a LazyVGrid layout based on the steps outlined in this AppCoda post: https://www.appcoda.com/learnswiftui/swiftui-gridlayout.html (minus the ability to change layouts).

I'm now trying to allow users to save an image to their camera roll by interacting with an image in the grid, however I'm having trouble pinning down the right steps to get the image at the index the user interacts with. I've thought about adding a Button on top of the Image with something like

```
...
ForEach(imageSet.indices) { index in
Button(action: {
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageSet[index], nil, nil, nil)
}) {
Image(imageSet[index].name)
.resizable()
...
```

but this results with the error `Cannot convert value of type 'Photo' to expected argument type 'UIImage'`

How can I save the image at the specified index to the Photo Library?
Hey thanks!

Comment: it should be UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(named: imageSet[index].name), nil, nil, nil)

Comment: Beautiful, thank you @raja!